# Convert list of tuples to named dictionary list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and have a data in the form of list of tuples with Name, Age and Salary

```
data = [('Alex', 21, 2000),('James', 25, 5000),('Mike', 30, 9000)]
```

I want have converted this data to dictionary list:

```
val_name = {tup[0]: tup[1:] for tup in data}
```

Output:

```
{'James': (25, 5000), 'Mike': (30, 9000), 'Alex': (21, 2000)}
```

Now, I want to access this dictionary values using variable name like:

```
val_name['Mike']['Age']  # should give me output as 30.

val_name['Mike']['Salary']  # should give me output as 9000.
```

Could you please suggest the pythonic way to achieve it?

Comment: The value in your outer dictionary should *also* be a dictionary, not just `tup[1:]`.

Comment: You should not use Python 2. It is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use names as key you need to have a dictionary for them as well:

```
val_name = {tup[0]: {'Age': tup[1], 'Salary': tup[2]} for tup in data}
```